# Returning empty venue data in FQL?

Tags: arrays, facebook, events, facebook-fql

My problem is that it seems for a few events there is simply no venue data at all.. for example this event (code):

SELECT name, location, attending_count, venue, eid FROM event WHERE eid = '447067818737101'

Is it possible to search for events where no venue data exists, like addig this to the code and the result still appear?

SELECT name, location, attending_count, venue, eid FROM event WHERE eid = '447067818737101'
AND venue.city = NULL OR venue.city = ""

**My goal is to select from many event results ONLY the ones WITHOUT venue.city data in the final code!**

UPDATE:
Solution for those who may have problems with events where venue data is not available:
strlen(venue.city) = 0 , if no city in venue struct it is simply equal to zero length string, and this surely works on other missing venue elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your use of AND and OR operator. You must know that AND operator has a precedence over OR operator. Therefore, your query will be executed as:

`SELECT name, location, attending_count, venue, eid FROM event WHERE (eid = '447067818737101' AND venue.city = NULL) OR venue.city = ""`

So instead, you can try:

`SELECT name, location, attending_count, venue, eid FROM event WHERE eid = '447067818737101' AND venue.city IS NULL`

Comment: Thanks for answer! Unfortunately the problem still persist as "(#602) NULL is not a member of the event table." and with using only the '' as venue.city = '' it does not return the event in the results tab..

Comment: I've many events from many cities around the world and many more which has no venue data at all, BUT I want to return those events ONLY that has no venue data especially venue.city :)

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer. Checkout if it works.

Comment: BUT I just found an AWESOME SOLUTION!!
strlen(venue.city) = 0
venue.city is a string so if it is empty it is equal 0 :))

Comment: Hey, that's nice. Nice trick. I'm glad you were able to work out. I think it would have even worked with `venue IS NULL`.
Anyways, good luck with your work.